# A question about whether a term exists indicating inner product of unknown coefficient vector and known function vector

Tags: inner-products

Let us consider an undetermined polynomial function $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$.
In the function $c_0, c_1$ and $c_2$ are unknown coefficients.
So one can express undetermined function as $f(C)=\operatorname{dot}(C,X)$
where $C=\begin{pmatrix}{c_0\\c_1\\c_2}\end{pmatrix}$ is an unknown coefficient vector
and $X=\begin{pmatrix}{1\\x\\x^2}\end{pmatrix}$ is a known function vector.
In this case, how can I call this format of the function $f(x)$?
Is there a term for this format?

Comment: I edited your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I don't know a name for that function, but it is a different function :$k^3\rightarrow k$ whereas $f:k\rightarrow k$ if you are working over the field $k$ and should be denoted with some different letter ,e.g. $\hat{f}$ or $f_X$ to indicate its dependence on $X$

Comment: Thanks for re-typing the formula :)

Comment: You're welcome. These two functions are just very loosely related. If you could provide more context you have a much better chance to get a helpful answer.